# Error on creating and verifying signed data

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm using some example code from *Wrox Beginning Cryptography with Java*. Line 24 of the code (below) shows me an error in Eclipse.

```
X509CertSelector signerConstraints = signer.getSID();
```

Eclipse error:

> *Type mismatch: cannot convert from SignerId to X509CertSelector*

Here is the full example:

```
package chapter9;

import java.security.cert.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationStore;

/**
 * Base class for signed examples.
 */
public class SignedDataProcessor {
    /**
     * Return a boolean array representing keyUsage with digitalSignature set.
     */
    static boolean[] getKeyUsageForSignature() {
        boolean[] val = new boolean[9];
        val[0] = true;

        return val;
    }

    /**
     * Take a CMS SignedData message and a trust anchor and determine if
     * the message is signed with a valid signature from a end entity
     * entity certificate recognized by the trust anchor rootCert.
     */
     public static boolean isValid(
         CMSSignedData   signedData,
         X509Certificate rootCert) throws Exception {
        CertStore certsAndCRLs = signedData.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC");
        SignerInformationStore  signers = signedData.getSignerInfos();
        Iterator it = signers.getSigners().iterator();

        if (it.hasNext()) {
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation)it.next();
            X509CertSelector signerConstraints = signer.getSID();

            signerConstraints.setKeyUsage(getKeyUsageForSignature());

            PKIXCertPathBuilderResult result = 
                Utils.buildPath(rootCert, signer.getSID(), certsAndCRLs);

            return signer.verify(result.getPublicKey(), "BC");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: please, post link to that example code

Comment: You might want to check the source you are copying from, because the BouncyCastle [documentation for SignerInformation](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/SignerInformation.html) clearly identifies the return type of getSID as being a SignerID.

Comment: Nikolay, the code is above content and it is from a book as I mentioned before.

Comment: I found the answer: Just upgrade to bcprov-jdk16-145.jar, bcmail-jdk16-145.jar..

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: Just upgrade to bcprov-jdk16-145.jar, bcmail-jdk16-145.jar..